# How to locate a specific html row containing specific text with Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, search, beautifulsoup

I am looking through HTML to find a name value pair that is stored in a row.  I cannot figure out how to specify the text that I am searching for in the beautiful soup find command.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''\
<tr>
    <td>Project ID:</td>
    <td>
        <span>112120</span></td>
</tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for element in soup.find_all("td", text="Project ID:")
    print (element)
    print (element.next_sibiling)
```

When I run this code, I get no results.

I realize I could return all "td" elements and search each one for "Project ID:" but that seems like a lot of work as the documents that I am searching have a large number of rows and elements.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want the output for the above sample data to be?  Just `1121201`?

Comment: I expected it to return the object with matching text (<td>Project ID:</td>) so that I could navigate to the next object which contains the value for the "project ID" = "1121201". 
I have multiple name/value pairs that I want to locate within the document.  So it would be ideal to search for each one and then locate the value.   There are many name/value pairs in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with everything in BeautifulSoup, you have many alternatives. For value pairs I tend to use `zip()` function most:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''\
<tr>
    <td>Project ID:</td>
    <td>
        <span>112120</span></td>
</tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# option 1
td = soup.select('td')
for name, value in zip(td, td[1:]):
    print(name.text, value.text)

# option 2
td = soup.find(lambda t: t.text.strip()=='Project ID:').parent.select('td')
for name, value in zip(td, td[1:]):
    print(name.text, value.text)

# option 3
td1 = soup.find(lambda t: t.text.strip()=='Project ID:')
td2 = td1.find_next('td')
print(td1.text, td2.text)
```

Every option prints:

```
Project ID: 
112120
```

**Option 1** finds all `<td>` and zips them together to get desired value pairs.

**Option 2** finds tag with text 'Project ID:', finds parent (`<tr>`) and zips `<td>`s together like in Option 1.

**Option 3** finds tag with text 'Project ID:', finds next `<td>` tag and prints text of both of them.

Comment: Options 2 and 3 worked perfectly!   However, I got some very strange results for option 1 when there were more than one <tr/> name/ value pair.  I expected one name/value pair for each <tr/> but it appears to embed the previous with the next pair.
I noticed you switched the parser, could that cause the strange behavior?

Comment: @DougBower Option 1 depends a lot on structure of your whole page (how many of `<td>` are on it, are all `<td>` paired?, and so on. More than often is useful to select concrete row and do pairs only in that row.

Comment: I am not familiar with what the lambda does in this routine?  Is it just stripping the text 'Project Id:'?    How would I change the search to find a cell that "contains" a value rather than equals?

Comment: @DougBower No, the `str.strip()` method strips the string of surrounding whitespace characters, eg `"  hello  ".strip()` becomes `"hello"`.